# Not able to remotely connect HBase from java Application

Tags: hbase

I have installed HBase on Linux Machine(192.168.113.27) and now I have written some    sample Code in Eclipse IDE on Windows Machine using JAVA API to communicate with HBase on Linux Machine. I have created "users" table on HBase on Linux Machine.

Client is connected to zookeeper as mentioned in the logs below: After that I am getting the exception "No Region found for users table". To resolve this I have read various threads and try various things but unable to solve it.

I have tried by changing local host to Linux machine IP (192.168.113.27) in the /conf/regionservers but still getting the same error.

Sample Code:

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.113.27");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");

HTableInterface usersTable = new HTable(conf, "users");
```

Logs on Client Side:

> 13/02/06 10:58:32 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment
>   complete on server 192.168.113.27/192.168.113.27:2181, sessionid =
>   0x13cae4bd91b0003, negotiated timeout = 40000

It means connection with zookeeper has been made.

Further on Excetion has come No Region found for "users" Table.

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to
>   find region for users,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:951)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:856)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:958)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:860)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:817)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:234)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.(HTable.java:174)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.(HTable.java:133)
>           at com.samsung.HBase.DBMain.putData(DBMain.java:32)

Answer (score 2):

Yes I had this issue as well. Took a while to figure out.

If you step into the HBase HConnectionManager code you will see this method being called.

```
   HRegionInterface getHRegionConnection(final String hostname, final int port,
```

Make sure the value of the hostname argument maps to a VALID IP address.

For instance, in my case I had a local hbase server on my local network with a hostname of "ubuntu" but the machine I was testing the hbase client with did not have a valid mapping IP address for hostname "ubuntu" in the windows 7 hosts file.

adding this entry to my windows 7 hosts file solved the problem

```
192.168.0.101   ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember something like this. It has to do with the fact that Zookeper returns a private IP address, if I remember correctly.

In your client side HBase configuration you should let `hbase.rootdir` point to an IP address instead of a hostname.

```
<configurtion>
    <property>
         <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
         <value>hdfs://<IP address>:<port>/<HBase location>/</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```